# There's a cycle in the delegation calls chain

Tags: kotlin, object, oop, parameters, constructor

I'm getting an error on my secondary constructor that says  "There's a cycle in the delegation calls chain". I'm almost certain that the issue is with my parameters, but I don't know how to fix this. Specifically, the issue is with "this(firstName, lastName, age)" after the secondary constructor. Would appreciate the help. Thanks.

fun main() {

```
var denis = Person("Default", " Name1", 31)
denis.age = 32
denis.hobby = "watching TV"
denis.sport = "Football"
denis.firstLastAge()
denis.stateHobby() //this refers to stateHobby fun in Person class

var john = Person("John", " Connor", 35)
john.age = 39
john.firstLastAge()
john.stateHobby()
```

}

class Person(var firstName: String?, var lastName: String?, var age: Int?) {

```
var male: String? = "male"
var female: String? = "female"

var hobby: String? = null
var sport: String? = null



init {
    println("Init(): firstName = $firstName, lastName = $lastName and age = $age")
}

fun firstLastAge() {
    println("firstLastAge(): Initialized a new person object with firstName" +
            " = $firstName and lastName = $lastName and $age")
}

fun stateHobby() {
    println("my hobby is $hobby and sport is $sport \n ------------------- \n")
}


constructor(firstName:String, lastName: String, age: String) : this(firstName, lastName, age) {
    this.male = male  
    this.female = female
    println("Constructor: $firstName, $lastName, $male \n")
    println("Constructor: $firstName, $lastName, $female \n")


}
```

}

Comment: What do you think the `this(firstName, lastName, age)` does and why did you put it there? You're right that that's the problem; it's calling the current constructor forever.

Comment: I kind of looked at it as explicitly calling the original constructor because apparently that is something that you have to do, but I never looked into what "this" does in that context as opposed to "this.male = male" and "this.female = female".

Comment: It's not calling the original constructor. It's calling the current constructor again. Are you sure you want to have two constructors here? It seems like your primary one can do everything this secondary one can do already.

Answer (score 1):

Your secondary constructor is trying to call itself. I assume you mean for it to call through to the primary constructor. However, your `age` cannot be upcast from a String to an Int, which is required for the primary constructor, so it's not resolving your `this()` call to the primary constructor.

One solution is to use `toIntOrNull()`. Alternatively, you could use `toInt()` if you want to fail fast for an invalid `age` String.

```
constructor(firstName:String, lastName: String, age: String) : this(firstName, lastName, age.toIntOrNull()) {
```

Comment: Side note, this secondary constructor seems unnecessary anyway. When would you ever need to wrap the `age` in a String before passing it to this constructor? And why would you only do that when the name parameters are non-nullable if the class supports null names? It seems to just make the class more convoluted.